# Does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that $P^n = I$, where $P$ is a rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that $P^n  = I$, where $P$ is a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix for a rotation of the plane by an angle $2\pi q$ radians?

1. if $q$ is a rational number
2. if $q$ is an irrational number

How should I go about answering this question? Do I need to think geometrically?

Comment: Notice that when you multiply a rotation matrix by itself, you again get a rotation matrix with the angle doubled. So, the only way to get identity after finitely many rotations is that $2\pi q n$ becomes an integer multiple of $2 \pi$. Is it possible for rational numbers? Is it possible for irrational numbers?

Comment: @lucyKel Here's a hint: if $q$ is a rational number, then how can you find the smallest positive integer $n$ for which $P^n = I$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I understand if $q$ was a positive integer, then it would work for all $n$, but what if it's not?

Comment: @lucyKel Try it, see what happens. For instance, try $q = 3/4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$P^n$$ corresponds to a rotation by angle $2\pi qn$ radians, or $qn$ full turns. $qn$ can only be an integer when $q$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

For $q \in \Bbb R$, let $P_q$ denote the $2 \times 2$ matrix that represents rotation by $2\pi q$.

**Hints:**

1. Show that $P_q^n = P_{nq}$ for all integers $n \ge 1$.
2. Show that $P_q = P_{q'}$ iff $q - q' \in \Bbb Z$.
3. Note that $I = P_0$. Conclude that $P_q^n = I$ iff $nq \in \Bbb Z$.
4. Find an $n$ which works for rational $q$ (think about the denominator).
5. Show that no $n$ works for irrational $q$. (what if some $n$ worked? Get a contradiction.)

Answer (score 0):

For a rotation matrix that rotates 2πq, $Pˆn = I$ iff nq is an integer. Therefore, for any rational number, there is an n that makes nq an integer (a rational number can be represented as $a/b$, coprime and integers hence if n is a multiple of b it works.

An irrational number, by definition, can not be written as $a/b$ hence no integer n can make nq an intger

hope that helps